# Proof: Brownian Motion Path Continious with Probability One

Tags: proof, brownian, motion

How can one show that the paths of the standard Wiener process are continuous in $T$ with
probability one? Can we just proof it with the assumption of independence ? Thank You in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: I applied Bayes law to $P(W_t | W_{t-1} + W_{t-2} + ... + W_{t-n})$, where $t > n$. Then I arranged the probability which should be equal to one as the past realisations should be independent from future observations.

Comment: What do you mean with ''prove'' this? It's part of the definition. A Brownian motion has almost surely continuous paths, i.e. the probability of getting a discontinuous path is zero. That's part of the usual [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process). You can't ''prove'' that the multiplication in a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is associative either. It's part of its definition.

Comment: Thas already an insight. My mathematical background is not that strong but I in class were given the statement 'That one can proof that the path of a brownian Motion is continous with the probability of one'. I thought I could solve it using induction.

Comment: How did you define a Wiener process? I guess a.s. continuous sample paths are part of that definition? You can prove that the sample paths of BM are a.s. non-differentiable ...

Comment: Yeah we defined it as a non-differentiable function. Okay Ill try the later one, thanks! I guess prooving the definition is just a tautology in that sense.

Comment: If you take of BM definition as "The Wiener process can be constructed as the scaling limit of a random walk, or other discrete-time stochastic processes with stationary independent increments." (from Wikipedia) I think proving continuity is of interest actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the distribution and independence of increments allows to prove $L^2$ (mean-square) continuity. Proving the a.s. continuity is much harder. Paul Lévy's construction of Brownian motion is related in [Le Gall](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319310886); an alternative is to construct the Brownian motion through Haar wavelet functions or Fourier series.

Comment: In the end I am looking for that proof! Ill have a look at the book, thank You!

Answer (score 3):

#### It's part of the definition

I'd just like to re-iterate the [comment by Kevin](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61452/proof-brownian-motion-path-continious-with-probability-one#comment89011_61452), (which as far as I can tell is the answer). There are three properties which define a standard Brownian motion / Wiener process:

1. Independent increments.
2. Normally distributed with variance equal to the time increment.
3. ***The path is continuous.***

Which hopefully any "standard" textbook on stochastics will re-iterate (Klebaner, Kloeden and Platen, Shreve, Oksendal, etc.).

However, as remarked [in this comment](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61452/proof-brownian-motion-path-continious-with-probability-one#comment89026_61452), it is possible to drop this assumption and start with alternative constructions/definitions, from which continuity might be a consequence rather than a postulate. However, I suspect this is both more advanced, more nuanced, and less standard, so I don't know any references for this starting point.